# Is it possible to get object instance member?

Tags: vb.net

I trying to get member name and it attribute. I used StackTrace, GetType(), MemberInfo etc but with no luck.

```
Class Test
    Class Test
    <Description("Some description")> Property TestProperty1 As Test2
    <Description("Some description")> Property TestProperty2 As Test2
    Sub New()
        TestProperty1 = New Test2("Test text")
        TestProperty2 = New Test2("")
    End Sub
End Class
End Class
Class Test2
    Property Text As String
    Sub New(ByVal SomeText As String)
        Text = SomeText
    End Sub
End Class
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited:=False)>
Class Description : Inherits Attribute
    Property Description As String
    Sub New(ByVal Value As String)
        Description = Value
    End Sub
End Class
```

I can get invocation method (caller member), Source class TypeInfo and its members but I can't determine what kind exactly member is true instance of my class.

Is there way to get member name "TestProperty1" of class "Test" from `Sub New(ByVal SomeText As String)` of class "Test2"?

Comment: Can you clarify what it is that you're trying to do?  Please provide more details in the example that clearly demonstrates where your code isn't working and what you want to happen.

Comment: My point is to get property name and access to property attribute. For example.

I declare "TestProperty1". Then I initialize this property by default constructor "New". On initialization (in the body of ```sub new```) I want to get declared property name of this instance (```TestProperty1```). I tried to invoke StackTrace and I can see invoker (class "Test") and all his members. But! I cannot identify which member is of my instance. I didn't see any unique parameter of type member parameters with which I can compare these instances.

Comment: I don't think that's supported.  The fundamental problem is that the assignment is a separate action from creating the new instance, so at the point of construction, the eventual destination is not available.

Comment: I think so too. Still thank you for the answer.

Comment: Okay, if I cannot get a name, how can I access to the "Description" attribute? I can't see it also. And (second question) how should attribute be created which will works as like "CallerMemberName"? I google it an found nothing about how exactly "CallerMemberName" works.

Comment: You can access attributes through reflection, see `PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute`.  As far as I know, `CallerMemberName` is "special" and involves the compiler itself making a substitution at compile-time.  The only way to replicate it would be to write your own plugin or analyzer or the like.

Comment: I cannot access to this attribute through ```PropertyInfo.GetCustomAttribute``` from class ```Test2```. Only from class ```Test``` (in which this attribute declared) I can assess to

Comment: The attribute is a property of the entity where it is declared (in this case, on properties `TestProperty1` and `TestProperty2`).  That's the only place you'll be able to access it.

Comment: I got it. Thank you! I new in attributes and don't understand many things